# Overheating (fire thrown out of the nozzle)

Tags: jet-engine, engine, jet, fuel-systems, turbojet

At first I copied https://www.jetcat.de/en/productdetails/produkte/jetcat/produkte/hobby/Engines/P160_rxi_b

Where I manufactured and installed all the parts and they are very similar to the original product (also similar to the same quality of metal)
I am facing two problems:
The first: When the engine is running, the engine does not start properly (taking into account that the balance is not good because it contains vibration) and also makes a popping sound.
[image]
The second problem: Since the start of operation, the temperature begins to rise dramatically, which causes the turbine disc and the nozzle to redden, as it throws a large proportion of the fire outside the combustion chamber.
Notes:
The work circuit is manufactured and programmed manually by me:
The kerosene pumping rate works with a continuous mechanism (I imitated the pumping algorithm in the main circuit) and I am not sure if I connected it correctly. After searching, I found that the fuel pumping algorithm should be used in particular, but I did not find sources to help me.
Are there any suggestions to help me find solutions to my problems?

Comment: Are you asking engineering suggestions based on an engine picture? That said this is an impressive achievement.

Comment: Amazing project! Bravo!

Comment: As it is, the way this question is asked is asking for opinions and much much too broad. Pick one of your issues (engine does not start properly, engine is not balanced, non-stable temperature, uncontrolled (or not properly controlled) fuel flow) and give us as much information as you are willing and ask a concrete and answerable with facts question on that single point. (and oh by the way, well done project, so far)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it about home made version of a MODEL aircraft engine and has very little in common with actual aircraft engines.

Comment: We have a SE just for that - http://drones.stackexchange.com/ - this would be a good question there, with more detail though.

Comment: It sorta looks like you are burning all the air going through the combustion can.  Normal jet engines only burn a minor fraction of the through flow and use the rest to cool the engine and contain the flame within the combustion can.  Is that what the Jet Cat does?

Comment: @JohnK Yes I have this problem? Can you guide me to the solution?

Comment: Well you'd have to have holes around the burner can and duct some of the air from the compressor around it on the inside and outside walls so that the air is forced into the can through the holes, which is how normal engines do it.  The details? I have no idea. Get a book on jet engine theory and start experimenting.